Tool To Easily Create Python Tkinter GUI
It would be very useful an editor like QtDesigner (drag-and-drop). Especially if it is codeless. Something like Figma that you deisgn the interface and then it just "translates" to code.
Requirements:

I can use it for commercial projects
preferably a website
Uses Python 3 and Tkinter latest versions.


I used to use VisualTK, but it is down for a while so now i'm using this website called customtkbuilder.com
It has pretty much all these requirements and it is pretty functional. You just design the interface and then click on "Translate To Code" and it will generate a python code.

Pretty much what i needed! thank you :)
